# Tensorflow classification labels datatype

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am using Tensorflow DNN model to do some **classification**.

I have a numerical (float32) data input but **string type output**.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None, n_classes])
```

When I try to define the loss and optimizer as below:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
```

I encounter an error that

> TypeError: sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits() got an unexpected
>   keyword argument 'labels'

I looked up the document from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn/classification), it said that

> logits and targets must have the same type and shape.

Do I need to convert the class into a floating number(hashing string to number)?

```
output_y = [["apple", "apple", "orange", "banana"]]
encoded_y = [[1], [1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using tensorflow v 0.10 the keyword for labels is targets. 
If you are using tensorflow v 1.0 then the keyword for labels is labels. 
As per the documentation your label vector should have the same type as logits, float 32 or float64.